# Problem with minified js file when using Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm having some problems with gulp with the generated minified files... The following section:

```js
for (const counter of counters) {
    //...
}
```

Is being minified as:

```js
for(const n of n){/**etc...*/}
```

Which brings problems of variable initialization...

My package.json is using these dependencies:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "del": "^3.0.0",
  "gulp": "^4.0.0",
  "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
  "gulp-cssmin": "^0.2.0",
  "gulp-htmlmin": "^3.0.0",
  "gulp-terser": "^1.4.0",
  "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
  "merge-stream": "^1.0.1"
}
```

And the gulpfile.js looks as follow:

```js
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin'),
    htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    merge = require('merge-stream'),
    del = require('del'),
    bundleconfig = require('./bundleconfig.json'); // this file contains the route for the original js files
const terser = require('gulp-terser');

const regex = {
    js: /\.js$/
};

// I've removed css and html minification operations

gulp.task('min:js', async function () {
    merge(getBundles(regex.js).map(bundle => {
        return gulp.src(bundle.inputFiles, { base: '.' })
            .pipe(concat(bundle.outputFileName))
            .pipe(terser())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
    }))
});

gulp.task('min', gulp.series(['min:js']));

gulp.task('clean', () => {
    return del(bundleconfig.map(bundle => bundle.outputFileName));
});

gulp.task('watch', () => {
    getBundles(regex.js).forEach(
        bundle => gulp.watch(bundle.inputFiles, gulp.series(["min:js"])));
});

const getBundles = (regexPattern) => {
    return bundleconfig.filter(bundle => {
        return regexPattern.test(bundle.outputFileName);
    });
};

gulp.task('default', gulp.series("min"));
```

I don't know why the minified file is like that, I tried to minify the same file using https://javascript-minifier.com/ and this problem isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is being `mangled` by the terser. Set the mangle flag to false and your problem should be solved.

You can refer to how to disable the flag here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser